# Need help saving id automatically in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have just started using `laravel` version 5.5.13. And I have encountered some problem when doing a one to many relationship table. I had followed this tutorial

https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-guide-to-using-eloquent-orm-in-laravel

When doing it but there was a part where I would need to assign the id manually(bear_id). Is there any way to do it automatically for it? And after assigning the id how do you get the data from it.

Blade.php

For the bear:
`{{Form::text('name_of_bear, '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}`

For the fish:
`<input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" name="type_of_fish[]" value="Salmon"> Salmon and <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" name="type_of_fish[]" value="Sardine"> Sardine`

Bear table:

```
Schema::create('bears, function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';  
            $table->string(name); 
            $table->timestamps();
});
```

Fish table:

```
Schema::create(fishs, function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';  
            $table->string(name); 
            $table->integer(bear_id);
            $table->timestamps();
});
```

Fish model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Eloquent;


class fish extends Eloquent
{
        protected $fillable = array('name', 'bear_id');

    // DEFINE RELATIONSHIPS 
    public function bears() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\bear);
    }
}
```

Bear Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Eloquent;

class bear extends Eloquent
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public function fishs() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\fish,'bear_id');
    }
}
```

I know there are some other method to do it such as attaching it or associating it but I don't really know how to use it. So would it be possible to show some example for me for referencing?

What I want:
1. For example, 1 bear (bear_id = 1) can have many fish (fish_id = 1 and 2), how do you do this?
2. And how do you get the data from it as my bear_id is 0 (inside database) and don't quite know how to use other methods such as attaching or associate or pivot

Answer (score 1):

Let's say there is a `bear_id` column in your `fish` database table and your bear-fish relationship is defined like this:

```
class Bear extends Model
{
    public function fish()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Fish');
    }
}
```

Associating fish with the bear can then be done manually like this:

```
$fish->bear_id = $bear->id;    
$fish->save();
```

Or you can create the relationship via the relationship method:

```
$bear->fish()->save($fish);
```

Comment: But how do I relate back together with the data that I had put in. Let say I used form to put in (eg: {{Form::text('name_of_bear), '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}} and for the fish I used textbox (eg:" <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" name="type_of_fish[]" value="Salmon"> Salmon" and "<input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" name="type_of_fish[]" value="Sardine"> Sardine")

Comment: I suggest you elaborate on your original question. It's not clear whether you are creating new bears and fish or updating existing ones. Do you know how to process data from the form and save it into database? Sorry for the questions by it's really time-consuming to read through the whole schotch.io tutorial and try to guess where you're stuck at.

Comment: Hi Matey, tks for the reply, I have changed the question already could you help me look at it again and the data that are submitted through the form are already save into the database but I do not know how to get it like showing this certain bear have eaten what kind of fish

Comment: I'm sorry, you're asking many questions at once: why is bear_id 0, how to set bear_id manually, how to set it automatically, how to show which fish a certain bear has eaten. You'd have greater chances on getting a good answer if you ask your question clearly.

Comment: So sorry for the confusion. Maybe I ask one at a time first. Firstly I want to save my data into the database so that my bear_id is 1, 2, 3 and so on. (id will always increase by 1 whenever a new data entry has been added) But my situation right now is that the bear_id is 0 whenever I saved it inside into the database

Comment: Then your problem is not with the relationship but with saving models to database. You should take a few steps back and try fixing that first.

Comment: Hi, I manage to save my data into the database through the use of this command "$bear = Bear::create(['Name' => $request->input('name_of_bear')]);
$bear->fishes()->create(['type_of_fish' => $fishType);" But if I were to try and save another field from bear table such as type_of_bear it would just remain blank("$bear->bears()->create(['type_of_bear' => $BearType);" )

Comment: Please, try some other basic Laravel tutorials from scratch. What you're attempting to do reveals that you have missed the ground concepts of models and relationships in Laravel and it's beyond the scope of StackOverflow to provide you with a complex help.